# Mapping function from 2D to 1D

Tags: mapping, 2d, element

I have 2D elements distributed in a space of [-4, +4] and want to convert any point in the 2D space to a 1D real-valued number such that 1st quadrant [+, +] should have higher values (importance), 2nd and 3rd quadrant [+, -] and [-, +] should be next, and the 4th quadrant [-, -] should have the least values.

How can I have such a mapping function!

Thanks!